# Populating ListView from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, android, json

I have a database in phpMyAdmin. I want to take information from a table and use it to populate a `ListView` in my Android app.

I created a PHP file :

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="ltc";

$con= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$BD= mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$query=mysql_query("select * from posts");
$num=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num==1)
{
    while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $output=$list;
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
        mysql_close();
    }
?>
```

And I created a `ListView` in Android. How can I get the information and put it in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PHP file outputs a correct JSON; your next steps will be calling the URL to reach this JSON with HttpGet. This will give you back a response, which is the JSON as a string.

This response you'll have to parse. You could use 'gson' for that. 
Resulting from that you can fill some list, object(s) or database and use that to fill your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You may call your php page with a method like this one:

```
         public static String getWebData(String url) {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
            // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

             // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpGet httpgett = null;

                httpgett = new HttpGet(url);


        String result="";
            try {


                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpgett);
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("--->" + "ClientProtocolException" + e.getMessage());
                return "";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                return "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                return "";
            }


                return result;
            }
```

One you have your data, you can put it into your  ListView